# JIBX - ant script issue

Tags: java, xml, ant, jibx

I have a problem with jibx and creating jar. I use **Netbeans** IDE.

In **build.xml** i have:

```
<import file="nbproject/jibx.xml"/>
<import file="nbproject/build-impl.xml"/>
<target name="-pre-compile" depends="jibx-bind"/>
<target name="-post-compile"  depends="jibx-postcompile">
    <copy toDir="${basedir}/${build.dir}/classes" overwrite="true">
        <fileset dir="${basedir}/${build.dir}/jibx/classes">
            <include name="**/*"/>
        </fileset>
    </copy>
</target>

<target name="-pre-jar"  depends="jibx-postcompile">
    <copy toDir="${basedir}/${build.dir}/classes" overwrite="true">
        <fileset dir="${basedir}/${build.dir}/jibx/classes">
            <include name="**/*"/>
        </fileset>
    </copy>
</target>
```

in **jibx.xml** i have:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project>
    <!-- generate using default settings -->
    <target name="jibx-codegen" >
        <echo message="Running code generation from schema"/>
        <java classname="org.jibx.schema.codegen.CodeGen" fork="yes" failonerror="true">
            <arg value="--generate-all=true"/>
            <arg value="-n"/>
            <arg value="jibxmodel"/>
            <arg value="-t"/>
            <arg value="${basedir}/${build.dir}/jibx/src"/>
            <arg value="src/xmlresource/XSD_final2.xsd"/>
            <classpath path="${javac.classpath}"/>
        </java>
        <move toDir="${src.dir}" overwrite="true">
            <fileset dir="${basedir}/${build.dir}/jibx/src">
                <include name="**/*.java"/>
            </fileset>
        </move>
        <move toDir="${src.dir}/xmlresource/" overwrite="true">
            <fileset dir="${basedir}/${build.dir}/jibx/src">
                <include name="**/*.xml"/>
                <include name="**/binding.xml"/>
            </fileset>
        </move>
    </target>

  <!-- bind as a separate step -->
    <target name="jibx-bind" depends="jibx-compile">
        <echo message="Running JiBX binding compiler : ${basedir}/${build.dir}/classes"/>
        <taskdef name="bind" classname="org.jibx.binding.ant.CompileTask">
            <classpath path="${javac.classpath}"/>
        </taskdef>
        <bind binding="${basedir}/src/xmlresource/binding.xml">
            <classpathset dir="${basedir}/${build.dir}/jibx/classes"/>
        </bind>
        <copy toDir="${basedir}/${build.dir}/classes" overwrite="true">
            <fileset dir="${basedir}/${build.dir}/jibx/classes">
                <include name="**/*"/>
            </fileset>
        </copy>
    </target>

  <!-- compile the classes -->
    <!--target name="jibx-compile" depends="jibx-codegen"-->
    <target name="jibx-compile">   
        <echo message="Compiling JiBX Java source code"/>
        <mkdir dir="${basedir}/${build.dir}/jibx/classes"/>
        <javac srcdir="${basedir}/${src.dir}/jibxmodel" destdir="${basedir}/${build.dir}/jibx/classes" debug="on" source="1.5">
            <classpath path="${javac.classpath}/classes"/>
        </javac>
    </target>

    <target name="jibx-postcompile" depends="jibx-bind">
        <copy toDir="${basedir}/${build.dir}/classes" overwrite="true">
            <fileset dir="${basedir}/${build.dir}/jibx/classes">
                <include name="**/*"/>
            </fileset>
        </copy>
    </target>
</project>
```

Jibx compiled files go to ${build.dir}/jibx/classes
When packaged, jibx doesn't seam to work. What do i need to change in ant script? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: "When packaged, jibx doesn't seam to work" - need more info

Comment: when i call jar target it overwrites jibx enhanced classes with new ones.

Comment: Show us the jar target from ant build.xml file. Better: shows us full content of both ant and jibx xml files.